# abuseipdb API2 check using php-cURL

Tags: php-curl

I'm trying to use abuseipdb API2 to check IP address reputations fro my email servers
The example given in the docs only covers shell curl

the problem is that I cannot convert shell curls --data-urlencode "ipAddress=118.25.6.39" into php-cURL
GEt variable does not work, post is not permitted, headers containing the IP address are not accepted>
All fails with : "detail":"The ip address field is required.","status":422

```
My Code:
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.abuseipdb.com/api/v2/check?'.urlencode("ipAddress=127.0.0.2") );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Key: <API-KEY>';
$headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

abuseipdb API2 Code:
curl -G https://api.abuseipdb.com/api/v2/check \
--data-urlencode "ipAddress=118.25.6.39" \
-d maxAgeInDays=90 \
-d verbose \
-H "Key: $YOUR_API_KEY" \
-H "Accept: application/json"
```

Answer (score 2):

this works for me.

```
//Setup
$api_key = 'REPLACE_YOUR_KEY';
$abuseipdb_endponint = 'https://api.abuseipdb.com/api/v2/check';
$ipToCheck = 'REPLACE_IP';

$headers =  array(
    'Key: ' . $api_key,
    'Accept: application/json'
);

//cURL Work
$curlObj = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_URL, ($abuseipdb_endponint . '?ipAddress=' . $ipToCheck));            
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);

$curl_response = curl_exec($curlObj);
print_r($curl_response);

curl_close($curlObj);
```

Response example:

```
{"data":{"ipAddress":"79.127.127.253","isPublic":true,"ipVersion":4,"isWhitelisted":false,"abuseConfidenceScore":100,"countryCode":"IR","usageType":"Data Center\/Web Hosting\/Transit","isp":"AsiaTech Data Transfer Inc PLC","domain":"asiatech.ir","totalReports":80,"lastReportedAt":"2019-04-24T01:44:51+01:00"}}[Finished in 0.9s]
```

Comment: This code almost complete because it needs `-d verbose` option. Without this, you won't be able to query the Country Name (limited by the API). How do you put this option `-d verbose` in the curl

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get Verbose data, all in an HTTP GET Query.

```
$key = "key";
$ip = "1.1.1.1";
$data = file_get_contents("https://api.abuseipdb.com/api/v2/check?ipAddress=$ip&maxAgeInDays=90&verbose&key=$key");
var_dump($data);
```